Login and create account buttons don’t work
I created a login screen in Java that has two buttons: Login and CreateAccount. These buttons were working initially, but after I started working on a different screen, they suddenly don't work anymore. I know it's not the actual login and create account methods that are causing the issue because using the enter key to login and the tab to create an account still work.
Here is my login.fxml file:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.14-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="edu.virginia.sde.reviews.LoginController">
   <center>
      <VBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="errorLabel" textFill="RED" wrapText="true">
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font>
               <padding>
                  <Insets left="25.0" right="25.0" />
               </padding>
            </Label>
            <Label alignment="CENTER" contentDisplay="RIGHT" text="Username">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
               <graphic>
                  <TextField fx:id="usernameField" onKeyPressed="#handleKeyPress" promptText="Enter your username...">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="14.0" />
                     </font>
                  </TextField>
               </graphic>
            </Label>
            <Label contentDisplay="RIGHT" text="Password">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
               <graphic>
                  <PasswordField fx:id="passwordField" onKeyPressed="#handleKeyPress" promptText="Enter your password...">
                     <font>
                        <Font size="14.0" />
                     </font>
                  </PasswordField>
               </graphic>
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="resultLabel" text="Press ENTER to log in, or TAB to create an account.">
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Label>
            <Label fx:id="infoLabel" alignment="CENTER" text="Passwords must be at least 8 characters long." wrapText="true">
               <font>
                  <Font size="14.0" />
               </font>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="5.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Label>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleLogin" text="Login">
               <font>
                  <Font size="20.0" />
               </font>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleAccountCreation" text="Create an Account">
               <font>
                  <Font size="20.0" />
               </font>
               <VBox.margin>
                  <Insets top="10.0" />
               </VBox.margin>
            </Button>
         </children>
         <BorderPane.margin>
            <Insets top="175.0" />
         </BorderPane.margin>
      </VBox>
   </center>
   <bottom>
      <AnchorPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
         <children>
            <Button alignment="CENTER" layoutX="504.0" layoutY="139.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleClose" text="Close" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="14.599999999999994" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="14.399999999999977">
               <font>
                  <Font size="22.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </AnchorPane>
   </bottom>
</BorderPane>

Here is my LoginController.java file:
package edu.virginia.sde.reviews;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class LoginController {
    @FXML
    private TextField usernameField;

    @FXML
    private TextField passwordField;

    @FXML
    private Label resultLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label infoLabel;

    @FXML
    private Label errorLabel;

    private CurrentUser currentUser = CurrentUser.getInstance();
    private Stage primaryStage;

    public void setPrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage) {
        this.primaryStage = primaryStage;
    }

    public void setCurrentUser(CurrentUser currentUser) {
        this.currentUser = currentUser;
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleLogin() {
        errorLabel.setText("");
        resultLabel.setText("Press ENTER to log in, or TAB to create an account.");
        infoLabel.setText("Passwords must be at least 8 characters long.");
        String username = usernameField.getText();
        String password = passwordField.getText();
        try {
            User user = DatabaseService.authenticateUser(username, password);
            if (user == null) {
                errorLabel.setText("Invalid username or password. If you don't have an account, re-enter your username and password and select \"Create Account\".");
            }
            else {
                currentUser.setUser(user);
                handleTransitionToCourseSearch();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            errorLabel.setText("Database error; please try again.");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleKeyPress() {
        usernameField.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                handleLogin();
            }
            else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
                handleAccountCreation();
            }
        });
        passwordField.setOnKeyPressed(event -> {
            if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.ENTER) {
                handleLogin();
            }
            else if (event.getCode() == KeyCode.TAB) {
                handleAccountCreation();
            }
        });
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleAccountCreation() {
        errorLabel.setText("");
        resultLabel.setText("Press ENTER to log in, or TAB to create an account.");
        infoLabel.setText("Passwords must be at least 8 characters long.");
        String username = usernameField.getText();
        String password = passwordField.getText();
        try {
            if (DatabaseService.isDuplicateUsername(username)) {
                errorLabel.setText("Username is already in use.");
            }
            else if (password.length() < 8) {
                errorLabel.setText("Password must be at least 8 characters.");
            }
            else {
                DatabaseService.createUser(username, password);
                infoLabel.setText("");
                resultLabel.setText("Account creation successful! Please log in.");
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            errorLabel.setText("Database error; please try again.");
        }
    }

    @FXML
    public void handleClose() {
        currentUser.clearUser();
        //URL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=exIQqcQ0lzI
        //Lines 111 and 112 were taken from 3:53 of this video.
        Stage stage = (Stage) resultLabel.getScene().getWindow();
        stage.close();
    }

    public void handleTransitionToCourseSearch() {
        try {
            var fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(CourseSearchController.class.getResource("course-search.fxml"));
            var newScene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
            var controller = (CourseSearchController) fxmlLoader.getController();
            controller.setPrimaryStage(primaryStage);
            controller.setCurrentUser(currentUser);
            controller.updateTable();
            primaryStage.setScene(newScene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}

And here is my application file:
package edu.virginia.sde.reviews;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.stage.WindowEvent;

public class CourseReviewsApplication extends Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        DatabaseService.initializeDatabase();
        FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("login.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(fxmlLoader.load());
        var controller = (LoginController) fxmlLoader.getController();
        controller.setPrimaryStage(stage);
        stage.setTitle("Course Reviews");
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }
}

What am I missing?
I tried using print statements to see if the issue was with the button or the logic, and through those discovered the issue was with the button itself. I tried Googling solutions but came up with nothing.

You may want to change tour post's title to something more appropriate, like "Login and Create Account Buttons Don’t Work, in some scenarios?"

The AnchorPane is covering the buttons and intercepting the mouse events. Use a more appropriate container, such as an HBox and get rid of the hard coded sizes.

You can see the issue if you add a partially-transparent color, for example style="-fx-background-color:#7f7fff7f;", to the anchor pane.

The problem was, as James said, the AnchorPane was covering the buttons.
I refactored your FXML to use more suitable containers (VBox, GridPane, and HBox) instead of relying on AnchorPane or hardcoded values.
Here’s the updated FXML:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.PasswordField?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextField?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.ColumnConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.RowConstraints?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<BorderPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.14-internal" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="edu.virginia.sde.reviews.LoginController">
    <center>
        <VBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10" style="-fx-padding: 20;">
            <children>
                <Label fx:id="errorLabel" textFill="RED" wrapText="true">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="14.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>

                <GridPane alignment="CENTER" hgap="10" vgap="10">
                    <children>
                        <Label text="Username:">
                            <font>
                                <Font size="16.0" />
                            </font>
                        </Label>
                        <TextField fx:id="usernameField" onKeyPressed="#handleKeyPress" promptText="Enter your username..." GridPane.columnIndex="1" />

                        <Label text="Password:" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
                            <font>
                                <Font size="16.0" />
                            </font>
                        </Label>
                        <PasswordField fx:id="passwordField" onKeyPressed="#handleKeyPress" promptText="Enter your password..." GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                    </children>
               <columnConstraints>
                  <ColumnConstraints />
                  <ColumnConstraints />
               </columnConstraints>
               <rowConstraints>
                  <RowConstraints />
                  <RowConstraints />
               </rowConstraints>
                </GridPane>

                <Label fx:id="resultLabel" text="Press ENTER to log in, or TAB to create an account." wrapText="true">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="14.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>

                <Label fx:id="infoLabel" text="Passwords must be at least 8 characters long." wrapText="true">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="14.0" />
                    </font>
                </Label>

                <HBox alignment="CENTER" spacing="10">
                    <children>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleLogin" text="Login">
                            <font>
                                <Font size="16.0" />
                            </font>
                        </Button>
                        <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleAccountCreation" text="Create an Account">
                            <font>
                                <Font size="16.0" />
                            </font>
                        </Button>
                    </children>
                </HBox>
            </children>
        </VBox>
    </center>

    <bottom>
        <HBox alignment="CENTER_RIGHT" style="-fx-padding: 10;">
            <children>
                <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleClose" text="Close">
                    <font>
                        <Font size="16.0" />
                    </font>
                </Button>
            </children>
        </HBox>
    </bottom>
</BorderPane>

